# Create directories using find and xarg

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My idea was to find all the .tar files in path $1 and then via xargs to make a directory with the same name as the .tar file in path $dirr which is read from the console.
Now this code works when I write the current location ( ./ ) but for paths like /home/user etc. it doesn't
Any idea how to make this code work?

```
read -p "Enter destination path:" dirr
find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.tar" -exec basename {} \; | xargs mkdir -p "$dirr"
```

Comment: What kind of output are you hoping to generate?  For example, if the file `foo.tar` exist, what directory do you want this to create?

Comment: @ghoti The directory would be _foo_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're looking for is to generate a directory for each tar file located in a particular directory, what about running a shell in your `-exec`?

```
read -p "Enter destination path:" dest
[ -d "$dest" ] || exit 1
find "$dest" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.tar" -exec sh -c 'mkdir -p "${0%.tar}"' {} \;
```

Or alternately, if you want to do this in shell alone, a for loop would probably do:

```
for tarfile in "$dest"/*.tar; do
  mkdir -p "${tarfile%.tar}"
done
```

Note that this may produce interesting results if no tar files exist in the destination directory.

Comment: Glad I could help! If you feel this sufficiently addresses your question, please feel free to click the green checkmark to the left of my answer. :)